# php mysql game map update automatically without refresh tab

Tags: php, mysql

i want to ask..
this script show 8 images width (as Y) and 5 images heigh (as X).
 I also have character (Example Location Y: 5, X:4).
all from database. Map, character position.
And to move the character, simply by pressing button "North", "West", "East", "South" (Example if user press button "South" then will X+1. mean cordinate player from X:4, Y:5 become X:5, Y:5) <-- its good so far.

**But, if player click button "South", the page is refresh.
My question is how to send data (form only button) without refresh page?**

This's my form to move player's coordinate looks like this: (index.php)

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input name="x+1" type="submit" value="North" /><br />
<input name="y+1" type="submit" value="West" /><input name="y-1" type="submit" value="East" /><br />
<input name="x-1" type="submit" value="South" />
</form>
```

and this is the process.. (index.php)

```
 $loca_x= $userrow["user_x"]; //x, up or down. From database user's x loc
   $loca_y= $userrow["user_y"]; //y , right or left. user's y locat.
    if (isset($_POST["x+1"])) { $loca_x--; if ($loca_x< 1) { $latitude = 1; $errormsg= "Edge of map!"; } }
    if (isset($_POST["x-1"])) { $loca_x++; if ($loca_x> 5) { $latitude = 5; $errormsg= "Edge of map!"; } }
    if (isset($_POST["y-1"])) { $loca++; if ($loca> 8) { $longitude = 8; $errormsg= "Edge of map!"; } }
    if (isset($_POST["y+1"])) { $loca--; if ($loca< 1) { $longitude = 1; $errormsg= "Edge of map!"; } }
```

**Also i have second question too..**
this script show grid map x, y from map.

```
for($x=1;$x<=5;$x++)
    {
        for($y=1;$y<=8;$y++)
        {
            $show_map_query = doquery("SELECT * FROM {{table}} WHERE x='$x' AND y ='$y'","explore");
        while($row_map = mysql_fetch_array($show_map_query)) {
                 if($userrow['user_x'] == $row_map['x'] && $userrow['user_y'] == $row_map['y']) {
            echo '<img src="petlist/'.$explore_pet['pet_pict'].'.gif" title="YOU ARE HERE -> X:'.$row_map['x'].' - Y:'.$row_map['y'].')" style="float: left;margin: 0;padding:0;" height="90" width="90">'; 
                 } else {
        echo '<img src="exploring/'.$row_map['object'].'.gif" title="(X:'.$row_map['x'].' - Y:'.$row_map['y'].')" style="float: left;margin: 0;padding:0;" height="90" width="90">';    
                 }

        }
    }
    }
```

when execute, this is the result: 
[THIS IS THE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAdgh.png)

But, its too heavy when browser load. how to show only 8 images. i mean like this:

```
[IMG][IMG][IMG]
[IMG][YOU][IMG]
[IMG][IMG][IMG]
```

and when player press button..all [img] change, but the character still in middle.
How to do this??

*NB: Sorry for this noob 2 question long bad english written.*

Comment: read about how to use ajax with php and html

Comment: its so hard for me to understand ajax..seriously, why even people understand that (o.O)  .

Comment: If you want stuff to happen in the database without having to refresh page, Ajax is the way. Get to understanding it, you won't regret it. 
Also, you might want to put the two parts of your question as separate questions.

Comment: Here's the basic thing to understand about AJAX: 
1. You have a server that has data and does things (your PHP code)
2. You have a client that receives this data and display things (usually HTML & Javascript)
3. Usually your client makes one call and gets back the **WHOLE** page and displays it and things end
4. In AJAX, your client keeps making small requests to the server and gets partial things form the server - not a whole page.

Comment: i have figured out my question 2. But i still dont know how to fix my question 1. Help anyone xd?